# What is a question that is an answer to itself?

Tags: questions, linguistics

Are there any questions in the English that, such that the question itself is an appropriate answer to the question itself?

Comment: You don't know?

Comment: This belongs on the [Puzzles.SE site](https://puzzles.stackexchange.com) (also not particularly specific to the English language)

Comment: Some rhetorical questions, asked to emphasise a point, in a sense are such as this. e.g. 
•Is the pope catholic?
•Is rain wet?
•You didn't possibly think I would say yes to that did you?

Comment: @Mitch it is *somewhat* specific to English, in that you won't always be able to translate answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book by Raymond Smullyan ...

[image: smulian]

Comment: I actually have that book.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible answers to this question. One such question is "What is a question that is an answer to itself?".

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're talking about?

> "Who's buried in Grant's tomb" question

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grant's_Tomb):

> On his radio and television show You Bet Your Life, comedian Groucho Marx often asked contestants, "Who was buried in Grant's Tomb?" The riddle is based on the use of the word "buried." The correct answer is "no one," since Grant and his wife are entombed in sarcophagi above ground in an atrium rather than being buried in the ground. However, Marx often accepted the answer "Grant," nonetheless, and awarded a consolation prize to those who gave it. He used the question, among several other comically simple ones, to ensure that everyone won a prize on the show.